# GRPC Interceptor for NodeJS/NestJS for dynamic transformation Struct, Any etc

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am a junior developer.

I am looking for an Interceptor implementation for automatic fromObject/toObject or wrap/unwrap of data for NodeJS.

Can you advise something? I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Thank you

Short code for example

street.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package street;

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message Street {
    optional string _id = 1;
    optional google.protobuf.Struct meta = 1000;
    optional int32 deletedAt = 1001;
    optional int32 createdAt = 1002;
    optional int32 updatedAt = 1003;
}
message StreetFind {
    optional string _id = 1;
    optional google.protobuf.Struct meta = 1000;
    optional int32 deletedAt = 1001;
    optional int32 createdAt = 1002;
    optional int32 updatedAt = 1003;
}
message StreetFindInput {
    StreetFind find = 1;
    Street input = 2;
}
```

Client

```
import { Struct } from "shared/proto/google/protobuf/struct";

strObj.meta = Struct.wrap(strObj.meta);
const street: StreetFindInput = {
    find: strObj as StreetFind,
    input: strObj as Street,
};
this.findStreet(street).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Server

```
import { GrpcMethod } from "@nestjs/microservices";
import { Metadata, ServerUnaryCall } from "@grpc/grpc-js";
import { Struct } from "shared/proto/google/protobuf/struct";

@GrpcMethod(classService.name, 'FindOneAndUpdate')
findOneAndUpdate(
    request: StreetFindInput,
    metadata?: Metadata
): Observable<Street> {
    if(typeof request.find.meta != "undefined") {
        request.find.meta = Struct.unwrap(request.find.meta);
        request.input.meta = Struct.unwrap(request.input.meta);
    }
    return from(this.grpcService.findOneAndUpdate(request.find as T5, request.input as T1));
}
```

I searched on google and on https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/awesome-grpc